# Transition for textarea label not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a form in which when `input` is clicked the label goes through a transition. If a value is entered in the input field, the label stays there. But the transition for when a value is entered is not working for `textarea`.
Input `labels` are behaving correctly but not the textrea `label`

My HTML for form:

```js
if($.trim($("textarea").val()) != '') {
              $("textarea").css("border: 2px solid blue");
}
```

```css
.input-field {
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 18px;
    }

    .input-field input,
    .input-field textarea {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 0 15px;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      background: transparent;
      color: black;
      outline: none;
    }

    .input-field label {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 15px;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      color: grey;
      font-size: 19px;
      pointer-events: none;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    input:focus,
    textarea:focus {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    input:focus~label,
    input:valid~label,
    textarea:focus~label,
   
    {
      top: -5px;
      left: 15px;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 0 2px;
      background: white;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="input-field">
          <input type="text" required spellcheck="false">
          <label>Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="text" required spellcheck="false">
          <label>Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
          <textarea style="min-height: 45px "> </textarea>
          <label>Your Message</label>
        </div>
```

I tried using jQuery `css()` to target the the textarea border on textarea input just to see if I can do the same for its `label`, but its not working.

I want the label for textarea to behave as ther labels for input are.

Comment: You should add an eventListener to the textarea. Your code will not get executed as it is now. It will only execute on pageload, but that’s it. You will want to apply the css every time the inout changes.

Comment: also  what has `border: 2px solid blue` anything to do with transitioning a label? Also, you're using `<label>` incorrectly. It's missing the `for=""` attribute - or rather wrap your INPUT and TEXTAREA inside LABEL, and use SPAN for the label's text - which requires a rewrite of your CSS logic.

Comment: Also `label,
   
    {` is invalid CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not need JavaScript (jQuery).

- Use the `<label>` semantically and properly. Wrap textarea and input into Label, or use the `for=""` attribute. I'll use the simpler wrapping method, and therefore put the actual label text into a SPAN Element.
- Use `placeholder=" "` and in CSS `:not(:placeholder-shown)+span {` to target the label SPAN when input or textarea has value (placeholder is not shown)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-field {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font: 1rem/1.4 sans-serif;
  
  & label {
    position: relative;
    
    & span {
      position: absolute;
      top: 1.24em;
      left: 1rem;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      color: grey;
      pointer-events: none;
      transform-origin: left;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
  }
  
  & input,
  & textarea {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    
    &:focus,
    &:not(:placeholder-shown) {
      border: 1px solid black;
      
      &+span {
        translate: 0 -2rem;
        scale: 0.8;
      }
    }
  }
  
  & textarea {
    min-height: 4rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <label>
    <input type="text" required spellcheck="false" placeholder=" ">
    <span>Name</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="input-field">
  <label>
    <input type="text" required spellcheck="false" placeholder=" ">
    <span>Email</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="input-field">
  <label>
    <textarea placeholder=" "></textarea>
    <span>Your Message</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the build-in functionality of the [attribute placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/placeholder). I know it is not doing a transition or anything, but it works and there is less code to maintain.

```css
.input-field {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.input-field input,
.input-field textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: transparent;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <input type="text" required spellcheck="false" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="input-field">
  <input type="text" required spellcheck="false" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div class="input-field">
  <textarea style="min-height: 45px" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
</div>
```